# Minimax Algorithm doesn't work as expected

Tags: algorithm, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, minimax, heuristics

I'm currently working on a checkers game against an AI in c#. I have tried to implement the AI using minimax algorithm. Although my function works the moves it selects are not logical at all. I tested it with many plays and algorithm just select bad moves when there are many better option. I don't think its due to the horizon problem because the move it makes have immediate consequences such as loosing a piece without capturing any of the opponents piece. 
Som notes about the code:

- My function takes a  8x8 2d array of enum `Pieces` which represents the checkers board.
- `BlackPlayer` is a bool value within the same class with function.
- `MyPiece(currentPiece)` function checks if the currentPiece is the same color with the AI.
- Since capture is mandatory in checkers function first checks if the `gameState` contains any capture moves. If not checks normal moves.
- I used alpha-beta pruning to make it more efficient.
- I used `CloneGameState(gameState)` function to copy the 2d array so that original array that represents the game never changes.

  ```
  public int Minimax (Pieces[,] gameState, int depth, bool is_maximizing, int alpha, int beta)
  {
      //Base Case - Return the board value 
      if (depth == 3)
          return HeuristicEvaluation(gameState);

      Move[] possibleMoves;
      int bestValue;
      bool currentSide;

      if (is_maximizing)
      {
          bestValue = int.MinValue;
          currentSide = BlackPlayer;
      }
      else
      {
          bestValue = int.MaxValue;
          currentSide = !BlackPlayer;
      }

      // check forced moves
      int moveCount = rules.GetCaptureMoves(gameState,out possibleMoves, currentSide);
      // if no forced moves get normal moves 
      if (moveCount < 1)
          moveCount = rules.GetNormalMoves(gameState,out possibleMoves, currentSide);

      // traverse moves
      for (int i = 0; i < moveCount; i++)
      {
          Pieces[,] newGameState = ApplyMove(CloneGameState(gameState), possibleMoves[i]);
          int newStateValue = Minimax(newGameState, depth + 1, !is_maximizing,alpha, beta);

          if (is_maximizing)
          {
              if (newStateValue > bestValue)
              {
                  bestValue = newStateValue;
                  if (depth == 0)
                      bestMove = possibleMoves[i];
                  if (newStateValue > alpha)
                      alpha = newStateValue;
                  if (alpha >= beta)
                      return bestValue;
              }
          }
          //Evaluation for min
          else
          {
              if (newStateValue < bestValue)
              {
                  bestValue = newStateValue;
                  if (newStateValue < beta)
                      beta = newStateValue;
                  if (alpha >= beta)
                      return bestValue;
              }
          }
      }
      return bestValue;
  }
  ```

The heuristics function:

```
public int HeuristicEvaluation(Pieces[,] gameState)
{
    int stateValue = 0;

    //use loops to check each piece 
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        int i = 0;
        if (j % 2 == 1)
            i++;

        for (; i < 8; i += 2)
        {
            Pieces currentPiece = gameState[i, j];

            if (currentPiece != Pieces.empty)
            {

                // if the current piece is mine
                if (MyPiece(currentPiece))
                {
                    // check if my piece is a king
                    if (currentPiece == Pieces.whiteKing || currentPiece == Pieces.blackKing)
                        stateValue += 80;
                    // my piece is a man
                    else
                    {
                        stateValue += 30;
                        // row values, closer to king zone higher the value 
                        if (currentPiece == Pieces.blackMan)
                        {
                            // black goes in reverse direction
                             int y = 7-j;
                             stateValue += y;
                        }
                        else
                             stateValue += j; 
                    }
                    // pieces on the edge are safe from capture
                    if (i == 0 ||i == 7 || j== 0 ||j ==7)
                    {
                        stateValue += 10;
                    }

                }

                // point reduction for enemy pieces
                else
                {
                    if (currentPiece == Pieces.whiteKing || currentPiece == Pieces.blackKing)
                        stateValue -= 80;
                    else
                    {
                        stateValue -= 20;

                        // row values, closer to king zone higher the value 
                        if (currentPiece == Pieces.blackMan )
                        {
                            // black goes in reverse direction
                            int y = 7-j;
                            stateValue -= y;
                        }
                        else
                            stateValue -= j;
                    }
                    // pieces on the edge cant be captured
                    if (i == 0 || i == 7 || j == 0 || j == 7)
                    {
                        stateValue -= 10;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return stateValue;
}
```

Comment: The heurstic function seems to give positive scores with respect to `MyPiece`, while the Maximizer seems to give positive scores in the view of the black player. I think your heuristic function should give its value with respect to the black player to be consistent. Also: in the Minimizer function you are not consistent with the last argument passed to `GetNormalMoves`. I think it should have the `!` before `BlackPlayer`.

Comment: `MyPiece(Piece)` just checks if piece belongs to the AI with respect to `BlackPlayer` bool (if black player piece must be blackMan or blackKing). You are right about the `GetNormalMoves` I fixed that typo now but problem still remains. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

First, I want to point out that your functions Maximizer and Minimizer can be combined in one function `Minimax(Pieces, gameState, depth, bool is_maximizing)` because their logic is almost the same except the couple of lines of code. So instead of calling Maximizer, you will call Minimax with is_maximizing set to true. And instead of calling Minimizer, just call Minimax with is_maximizing set to false. This will help to avoid repetition and will make your code more readable.

This first point leads us to a mistake in the algorithm. In the Minimize function you recursively call itself, while you should call the Maximize function.

Another point is the way you handle all valid moves in the given position. You don't have to separate processing of capture moves from non-capture ones. The reason is once again that the logic for processing both types of moves is the same. I suggest to create two functions - GenerateValidMoves() and SortValidMoves(). GenerateValidMoves() function will generate a list of all valid moves in the given position. After the moves list was generated, call SortValidMoves() to sort the list so that capture moves are located in the beginning of the list followed by non-capture moves.

Here is a simplified pseudocode for minimax:

```
Minimax(color, board, depth, is_max):
    if ((depth == DEPTH_CUTOFF) or IsTerminalNode()):
        return EvalBoard()
    best_score = is_max ? -infinity : infinity
    valid_moves = GenerateValidMoves(board, color)
    for curr_move in valid_moves:
        clone_board = board.clone()
        clone_board.make_move(curr_move)
        int curr_score = Minimax(opposite_color, clone_board, depth + 1, !is_max)
        if (is_max) {
            if (curr_score > best_score) {
                best_score = curr_score
                best_move = curr_move
            }
        } else {
            if (curr_score < best_score) {
                best_score = curr_score
                best_move = curr_move
            }
        }
    return best_score
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your time. I made my function more compact as you suggested. I'm testing it but I still observe some odd behavior. Yet I couldn't understand how to use one function to generate all the moves. AI should choose a capture move if any exist because its mandatory in checkers rules. I thought getting it separately would save from computing normal moves.

Comment: @Berkay I added minimax pseudocode to the answer which may be helpful.

Comment: @Berkay Oh, I forgot that capturing is mandatory in checkers. Now I see why separating moves makes sense. I think the way you rewrote it is fine. Another possible issue is - what happens when you call your Minimax for white pieces with depth == 0? I think you won't get the best move because there is no code for it in Evaluation for min part.

Comment: actually in the way I wrote it `BlackPlayer`'s false value represents white pieces. Thats why minimizer part calls it with `!BlackPlayer` ,opposite of the maximizer player. Since we want to get the best possible move for the AI, it always calls the minimax function with `is_maximizing` value true.

Comment: @Bekay What I mean is the following. Suppose computer plays white pieces and it's white's turn, so AI needs to make a move. In order to find the move, it needs to call Minimax. How would you call a `Minimax` function for white pieces? If you call it like this `Minimax(...,depth=0, true)` then `currentSide` is set to `BlackPlayer` which is incorrect (because it's white turn). If you call it like this `Minimax(...,depth=0, false)` then you will not find the best move, because there is no check for `depth == 0` in the else branch of `Minimax` function. Correct me if I'm missing something here.